# HyperLink with NavigateUrl with Eval(). Where is the mistake?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, eval, code-behind

First I was changing `HyperLink.NavigateUrl` in code-behind on `Page_Load()`.

But after I decided to do it in design using `Eval()` method.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
     NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Refuse.aspx?type={0}&id={1}", Eval("type"), Eval("id")) %>' Text="Refuse" />
```

or

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="urlRefuse" runat="server"
     NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Refuse.aspx?type={0}&id={1}", Request["type"], Request["id"]) %>' Text="Refuse" />
```

where `id` and `type` - are variables from `Request`.

But it doesn't work. Only raw text 'Refuse' is shown. Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hai, see this if it helps [http://forums.asp.net/p/1490115/3505218.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/p/1490115/3505218.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a method from post #2 and it doesn't work. I want to figure out where am I wrong..

Comment: Id prperty of ur hyperlink is missing... Is that causes error i dont know...

Comment: @Pandiya: Sounds mysteriously and in the same time - realistic. But unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("type","id", "~/Refuse.aspx?type={0}&id={1}") %>'

Comment: Try NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("Sync.aspx?Msg={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Msg"))%>'

Comment: Where you use the hyper within a datalist,gridview or the page

Answer (score 63, accepted):

this is working great

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("type","~/Refuse.aspx?type={0}") %>'
```

Comment: I stopped using web forms years ago, and yet I come years later to learn something like this was so easy.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}.aspx?ID={1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Post_ID")) %>'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try and ViewSource in your browser, what's being rendered to the client in your href? Is it what you expected?. If you are trying to use variables from the request collection you can't use Eval, you need to use the Request query string parameters.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
     NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Refuse.aspx?type={0}&id={1}", Request["type"], Request["id"]) %>' Text="Refuse" />
```

Comment: Next is being rendered: <a id="ctl00_commonForm_ctl01_urlRefuse">Refuse</a>.
Thanks for tip. I used it. The same result..

Comment: Are you trying to use values from the query string? Did you try and use Request["id"] instead of Eval("id")?

Comment: Try adding Page.DataBind() to your Page_Load.

Comment: I tried this myself, it worked. Make sure you have valid data in your query string parameters.

Comment: @Phaedrus where he is using the hyperlink within a datalist,gridview or the page

Comment: I already understood that I have to use Request["id"]. I do this. And current url where I'm testing is /Approve.aspx?type=request_exchange&id=2 a page loads a control without any GridView or other Views

Comment: (string)Eval("type") works only after this.DataBind() on Page_Load(). It works but it sucks :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" onclick='<%# String.Format("AcceptUser({0},{1})",Eval("UserId"), Eval("TsId")) %>' NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0)" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("CanDelete") %>'>Accept</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("type")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it worked for me:

```
Eval("type").ToString()
```