# Create computed column with string in formula

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to create a computed column in SQL SERVER and set the formula to this

```
([Category] +  '.aspx?ID=' + [Post_ID])
```

Not working though......what am i missing?

Category and Post_ID are current columns in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually sorted it out for me at the end.....

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("{0}.aspx?ID={1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Post_ID")) %>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you do

```
SELECT [Category] +  '.aspx?ID=' + [Post_ID]
FROM table
```

?

Try

```
SELECT CAST([Category] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '.aspx?ID=' CAST([Post_ID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM table
```

or specify max size depending on your columns' data type.

---

Above answer is bad. DON'T FORMAT ON DATA LAYER. FORMAT ON PRESENTATION LAYER, i.e. in mark-up. E.g.:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
    HeaderText="LinkHeader"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}.aspx?ID={1}" 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="Category,Post_ID"
    DataTextField="LinkName" />
```

(to work properly this requires also a field `LinkName` to exists in the resulting selection)

or

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat= "server"
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LinkName").ToString() %>' 
    NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category").ToString() + ".aspx?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Post_ID").ToString() />
```

Comment: How would I do it on this: NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Post_ID", ".aspx?ID={0}")%>'>

Comment: @Etienne: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779481/hyperlink-with-navigateurl-with-eval-where-is-a-mistake

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're probably missing a cast. I agree that this seems an unlikely candidate for a computed column though.

```
create table #t
(
Category varchar(50),
[Post_ID] int
)

alter table #t 
add comp as ([Category] +  '.aspx?ID=' + cast([Post_ID] as varchar(10)))
```

Comment: I think it's bad idea to create such computed column and much better - just format data on-the-fly on the presentation layer

Comment: @abatishchev I can't think of any circumstances where this column would be a good idea either.