# Operand "+" with Bind/Eval in aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have this aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="Firmierung">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "DetailInfo.aspx?Id={0}") %>' Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to add an if condition so that I can use operand + with Text, something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="Firmierung">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% if(Condition is true) { %>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "DetailInfo.aspx?Id={0}") %>' Text='<%#Bind("Name") + ("Active") %>' />
        <% } else { %>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "DetailInfo.aspx?Id={0}") %>' Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>' />
        <% } %> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I don't know how to use operand + in this case. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
Text='<%# String.Format({0}{1},Eval("Name"),Eval("Active")) %>'
```

OR

```
Text='<%# String.Format({0}{1},Bind("Name"),Bind("Active")) %>'
```

For more help visit the link:

[HyperLink with NavigateUrl with Eval(). Where is the mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779481/hyperlink-with-navigateurl-with-eval-where-is-the-mistake)

Comment: Hi, thanks your answer, that's what I was looking for, but there's a little error syntax in your answer, we need "" for {0}{1}. So, this is my code, worked like a charm : Text='<%# String.Format("{0} ({1})", Eval("Name"), Eval("Active")) %>'

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `Bind`. Although with `Eval` you can add some C# code with it, with `Bind` it is not possible. `Eval` is really a method call but `Bind` is just a declaration that turned by the framework to some binding code, and its format has to be `Bind("FieldName")` (You can add formatting though).

The `Hyperlink` `Text` property is not editable by the client so `Eval` should be enough and you can write it in one row.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" 
      NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "DetailInfo.aspx?Id={0}") %>' 
      Text='<%# Eval("Name") + (Condition ? + Eval("Active") : "") %>' />
```

Comment: so, as your suggestion, I did like : Text='<%# (bool) Eval("Active") ? Bind("Name") + "Active" : Bind("Name") %>' />    and I get this error : The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You can't do this. You can't add code to `Bind`. ou can use `Eval` only. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Magnus, this is not my answer. I'm rolling back. If you think otherwise please comment or write your own answer.

Comment: @AmiramKorach sorry about that, thought is was a syntax error.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: I resolved this problem, my answer is above. Thanks for your help :) . What I wanted was to check if this Name is Active (bool), then I print Hyperlink's Text is Name (Active), otherwise, Text is only Name. :)