# HyperLink with NavigateUrl with Eval() didn't fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I followed the answer on [HyperLink with NavigateUrl with Eval(). Where is the mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779481/hyperlink-with-navigateurl-with-eval-where-is-the-mistake). However it didn't open the page. Would someone tell me how to do it.

My code:

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionNumber") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("/orders/orderAction.aspx?orderID={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionNumber")%>)' Target="_blank"> </asp:HyperLink>
```

I checked the control in html code like this using development tool in IE:

```
 <a id="dgrd_ctl02_HyperLink1" href='<%#%20String.Format("/orders/orderBasics.aspx?orderID={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionNumber")%>)'>VA_QA_5666</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses are not quite correct at the end of your `NavigateUrl` expression:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("/orders/orderAction.aspx?orderID={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ActionNumber")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP is better to write routes in this way:

```
  ~/YourRoute/SubRoute
```

So in your code, you should have:

```
"~/orders/orderAction.aspx?orderID={0}"
```